# Unable to reinstall Couchbase in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, 22.04, dpkg

I'm unable to reinstall Counchbase (couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb). It seems uninstalling it is not correctly done. I have deleted all the folders and tmp files for dpkg, but I am still not able to reinstall it. Please help me to reinstall it. Deleting the OS and reinstalling will work, but it's not the best practice)

Systems: Ubuntu 22.04.
CB: couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb and couchbase-release-1.0-amd64.deb

I followed all steps given in the Counchbase document.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/install/ubuntu-debian-install.html

Deleted temp files and restarted my system but no luck.

These are the errors:

```
machine@machine-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg -i ./couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for machine: 
(Reading database ... 207604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/couchbase-server-community.prerm: 5: /opt/couchbase/bin/install/systemd-ctl: not found
dpkg: warning: old couchbase-server-community package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: /opt/couchbase/bin/install/systemd-ctl: not found
dpkg: error processing archive ./couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb (--install):
new couchbase-server-community package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
./couchbase-server-community_7.2.0-linux_amd64.deb
machine@machine-System-Product-Name:~$
```

```
machine@machine-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg -i ./couchbase-release-1.0-amd64.deb
dpkg: error: cannot access archive './couchbase-release-1.0-amd64.deb': No such file or directory
machine@machine-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo dpkg -i ./couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 207604 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb ...
Supported platforms are: Debian/wheezy,jessie,stretch and Ubuntu/precise,trusty,xenial,bionic
dpkg: error processing archive ./couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb (--install):
new couchbase-release package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
./couchbase-release-1.0-6-amd64.deb
machine@machine-System-Product-Name:~$
```